# Reproducing results from classic dropout paper

Tags: tensorflow, sparse, dropout, torch

In the classic paper "Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from
Overfitting", there is a figure comparing the features learned by a one-layer autoencoder trained on  MNIST with and without dropout. The features learned using dropout appear to be more meaningful. Does anyone know of a pytorch or tensorflow implementation that reproduces this result exactly or nearly exactly?

Specifically, I am trying to reproduce the pair of images below. The paper claims that these are both features learned with auto-encoders having a single hidden layer of 256 ReLU units. I believe that [this](https://github.com/nitishsrivastava/deepnet/tree/master) repo contains the original code, which I have not been able to get to run on my computer.

[image]